# ORA-01031: insufficient privileges when creating package

Tags: sql, oracle, package

I'm getting ORA-01031: insufficient privileges when creating a package my own schema.  Shouldn't I have complete control over my schema.  If this is not the case, what privileges does my schema need?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may need to have *GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO USERNAME*.

Answer (score 5):

If you are referencing tables that are not in your schema you may get this error even if you can select data from the tables. The problem is that permissions granted by roles work for sql but do not work for PL/SQL. PL/SQL requires the rights be granted to the user.

Another possible issue is that you do not have the create procedure system priviledge which is need to create procs.